# Swipe Gestures - Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I need my app to respond to a swipe gesture, and I got this code so far. But for some reason when I swipe, the app crashes. What's the problem please? I use swift 3 in xcode. Thank you

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


        switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                print("Swiped right")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
                print("Swiped down")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                print("Swiped left")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
                print("Swiped up")
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are asking about a crash, include the specific message you're getting, info about the call stack, and the specific line that's crashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to the error:- No method declared with Objective-C selector 'respondToSwipeGesture:'

It means that no method "respondToSwipeGesture" is found by the compiler and when you try to swipe the program tries to find this method and crashes as it is unable to find it.

Please provide actions like this:-

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))

let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
```

This will resolve your issue.